# httpd-2.4.53 on Rocky9 Proxy balancer

Tags: apache, rocky-os

It seems with httpd-2.4.53 on Rocky9 the <Proxy balancer://my_lb>  definition has to be within the VirtualHost definition.
If I put "" before <Proxy balancer://my_lb>  httpd won't start and says "Cannot find LB Method: byrequests".
But if I move "" to after "" of the balancer definition it works fine.
Documentation says it does not have to be inside VirtualHost definition but that seems to have changed?
Works fine outside VirtualHost with Rocky8 and httpd-2.4.37.

Any one else seen that?

This doesn't work:

```
    </VirtualHost>
    <Proxy balancer://cam_lb>
     BalancerMember https://myhost1:8443 ping=5 disablereuse=on retry=5 ttl=120
     BalancerMember https://myhost2:8443 ping=5 disablereuse=on retry=5 ttl=120
     Proxyset lbmethod=bytraffic
     Proxyset stickysession=JSESSIONID
    </Proxy>`
```

This does work:

```
    <Proxy balancer://cam_lb>
     BalancerMember https://myhost1:8443 ping=5 disablereuse=on retry=5 ttl=120
     BalancerMember https://myhost2:8443 ping=5 disablereuse=on retry=5 ttl=120
     Proxyset lbmethod=bytraffic
     Proxyset stickysession=JSESSIONID
    </Proxy>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: reason I care is because we use puppet to deploy apache and puppetlabs apache module does not have a way to include balancer config within VirtualHost definition, that I see.

Comment: I guess no one else uses apache puppet module with Rocky 9?